# Media Player onStop() inside Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, notifications

I am implementing media player in my alarm app.I am playing alarm on the basis of spinner values(i.e if user selects 3 alarm will start at given time and will repeat three times).Also i am sending notification from my activity to receiver and along with that the position of song and spinner value. Its all happening in Broadcast Receiver and its working fine.Alarm and notification is occurring on the given time.Now i have a cancel action on notification on click of it notification should dismiss and alarm should stop.Its all good with notification but i am unable to stop media player instantly. 
What is Happening now : If i am selecting 3 from spinner and selecting a random time,Alarm starts on the given time notification occurs and when i select cancel action notification disappears , media player stops but after completing the song.
What i want : I want to stop the song instantly as i select cancel action.
How should i do that?

Code in Context :

NewBroadCastReceiver.java

```
public class NewBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String STOP_ACTION = "cancel";
    public static String NOTIFY = "notify";
    int position;
    private static int count = 1;
    String mSong;
    Bundle mBundle;
    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";
    private static int id;
    Notification notification;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    int data = 0;
    private static boolean mStopFlag = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle = intent.getExtras();
        mSong = mBundle.getString("song");
        position = mBundle.getInt("position");

        if (NOTIFY.equals(action)) {
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Integer.parseInt(mSong));
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {


                    // mPlayer=mp;

                    if (count < position) {
                        if (!mStopFlag) {

                            Log.e("check1", "" + mStopFlag);
                            mPlayer.start();
                            count++;
                            Log.e("count if", "" + count);

                        } else {
                            try {
                                Log.e("check2", "" + mStopFlag);
                                Log.e("count else", "" + count);
                                //mPlayer.reset();
                                mPlayer.stop();

                                mPlayer.release();

                                mStopFlag = false;
                                count = 1;
                                Log.e("check2 else then left", "" + mStopFlag);
                                Log.e("count-reset", "" + count);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(" Activity", e.toString());
                            }

                        }


                    } else if (count >= position) {
                        //mPlayer.reset();
                        mPlayer.stop();
                        mPlayer.release();
                        count = 1;
                        mStopFlag = false;
                        Log.e("count sum position", "" + count);
                       /* int time=mp.getDuration();
                        mp.seekTo(time);*/


                    }

                }
            });
            mPlayer.start();

            Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
            id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
            notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

        } else if (STOP_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            mStopFlag = true;

            stopPlayer();


            notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID);
            id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
            Log.v(NewBroadCastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "stopped");


        }
    }


    public void stopPlayer() {
        try {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;

                Log.e("check3", "" + mStopFlag);

            } else {
                Log.e("null", "empty player");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PlayMorningMantraActivity.java

```
public class PlayMorningMantraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private Button mAlarm;
    private ImageButton mPlay;
    private String mSongName, mImage;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Integer itemPos;
    private Spinner mSpinner;
    private PendingIntent notifyIntent;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    int count = 1;
    private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    private ImageView mShowImage;
    private Context context;
    public static String NOTIFY = "notify";
    private static  String STOP_ACTION = "cancel";
    private Notification notification;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private RelativeLayout mBanner;
    private FlurryAdBanner mFlurryAdBanner = null;
    private String mAdSpaceName = "Mantra_Flurry_ads";;



    final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    String repeatTimes[] = {"03", "11", "21", "27", "54", "108"};
    String flags[] = {"Times", "Times", "Times", "Times", "Times", "Times"};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_mantra);
        mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_title);
        mBanner = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_layout);
        mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        mPlay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        mAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_alarm);
        mShowImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_show);




        Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        /*final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);*/

        toolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();

            }
        });


        mPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        mAlarm.setOnClickListener(this);

        mSongName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Mantra");

        mImage = getIntent().getStringExtra("Image");
        mShowImage.setBackgroundResource(Integer.parseInt(mImage));


        TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        TextView mDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_details);

        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica.ttf");

        mDetails.setTypeface(custom_font);
        mText.setTypeface(custom_font);


        mText.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Song"));
        mDetails.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Details"));

        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, repeatTimes);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        if ((Calendar.getInstance().HOUR_OF_DAY > 8 && Calendar.getInstance().HOUR_OF_DAY < 14)) {

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.play_morning_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        interstitialAd=new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.Interstitial_adMob));
        AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                //showInterstitial();
            }
        });
        mFlurryAdBanner = new FlurryAdBanner(this, mBanner, mAdSpaceName);
        /*mFlurryAdBanner.fetchAndDisplayAd();*/


        mFlurryAdBanner.setListener(bannerAdListener);


    }

    /*private void showInterstitial() {
        if(interstitialAd.isLoaded()){

            interstitialAd.show();
        }
    }*/
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this);
        // fetch and display ad for this ad space as soon as it is ready.
        mFlurryAdBanner.fetchAndDisplayAd();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
        mFlurryAdBanner.destroy();
    }
    FlurryAdBannerListener bannerAdListener = new FlurryAdBannerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFetched(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {
            mBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adBanner.displayAd();

        }

        @Override
        public void onRendered(FlurryAdBanner flurryAdBanner) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onShowFullscreen(FlurryAdBanner flurryAdBanner) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseFullscreen(FlurryAdBanner flurryAdBanner) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAppExit(FlurryAdBanner flurryAdBanner) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayMorningMantraActivity.this, "App Exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onClicked(FlurryAdBanner flurryAdBanner) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoCompleted(FlurryAdBanner flurryAdBanner) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FlurryAdBanner adBanner, FlurryAdErrorType adErrorType, int errorCode) {
            //mBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            adBanner.destroy();
        }

    };


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        itemPos = Integer.parseInt((repeatTimes[position]));


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_play) {
            mPlay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PlayMorningMantraActivity.this, Integer.parseInt(mSongName));
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (count < itemPos) {

                        mp.start();
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        mPlay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

                    }
                }


            });


            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mPlay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                count = 1;
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }

        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_alarm) {
            openTimePickerDialog(false);
        }
    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(PlayMorningMantraActivity.this, onTimeSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle(R.string.alarm);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
            = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
            if (hourOfDay >= 8 && hourOfDay <= 21) {

                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.play_morning_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {

                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(getNotification("Alarm"), calSet);


        }
    };

    private void setAlarm(Notification notification, Calendar targetCal) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayMorningMantraActivity.this, "This Alarm is Set For" + targetCal.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewBroadCastReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(NOTIFY);
        intent.putExtra(NewBroadCastReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        intent.putExtra(NewBroadCastReceiver.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("song", mSongName);
        bundle.putInt("position", itemPos);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }

    private Notification getNotification(String content) {

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Alarm Notification");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(this, NewBroadCastReceiver.class);
        cancelIntent.setAction(STOP_ACTION);
        cancelIntent.putExtra(NewBroadCastReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "CANCEL", pendingIntent);

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        finish();


    }


}
```